# How Can I add Hyperlink field to SharePoint Document library A Edit Item pointing TO Document library B in same site content?

Tags: form, url, hyperlink

I have a document library (Purchase Request System) that has a custom excel template tied to New Item.

The excel file has Macro button that saves back to that document library.

This all works fine, but AP Dept has asked me to add the ability to attach invoice and or Approved PO to the document list item.

As a workaround, someone has suggested to create a Hyperlink field and add the document url in the field. We can store the documents in another document library. This sounds great, but I need to automate this.

Is there a way to make a button or Linkn that displays in the original Document library A Edit Form linking back to Document library B ? ootb or code?

Answer (score 0):

In the list settings for document Library A you can create a lookup field in the document library that will link to the second document library.  This will allow you to select from a drop down the document in Library B in the edit form in Library A, creating a link to the document in B.

Comment: HI Thanks for answering, I tried your suggestion and I cannot seem to make a 2 way link. I created a document library B and called it Attachments. The I created a lookup column > get info from > DocLib A> "purchase request number" column> then from Doclib B (attachments) I hit upload link,select "Invoice 1" I see the list of purchase request numbers from DocLib A in the Form and I match to it. But when I go back to view DocLibA how can I view Attachment called "Invoice 1" ?

Comment: Mario, it's only a one way link, so if the lookup column is in Library B, once you select that from the drop down, it will then provide a link back to the document in library A.

Comment: from what drop down? sorry I think im getting tired.

Comment: When you create a lookup column in your library settings, it will display as a drop down in the library form, allowing you to select a value from whatever column you choose to link to in the other list.  When updated, this will link it to that item in the other library, in your case library B.